# View list of deleted files

Tags: rm, deleted-files

I have executed `rm -f *.gz` about 30 days ago. Is there any way to find out the list of files that were deleted?

Comment: How often do you run `updatedb` ? Do you have backups ?

Comment: @DarkHeart updatedb runs everyday and; no, there are no backups.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `debugfs` utility,

> debugfs is a simple to use RAM-based file system specially designed
>   for debugging purposes

First, run `debugfs /dev/sda2` in your terminal (replacing `/dev/sda2` with your own partition).

Once in debug mode, you can use the command `lsdel` to list inodes corresponding with deleted files.

> When files are removed in linux they are only un-linked but their
>   inodes (addresses in the disk where the file is actually present) are
>   not removed

**To get paths** of these deleted files you can use `debugfs -R "ncheck 320236"` replacing the number with your particular inode.

```
Inode   Pathname
320236  /path/to/file
```

From here you can also inspect the contents of deleted files with `cat`. (NOTE: You can also recover from here if necessary).

Reference [**here**](http://www.linuxweblog.com/undelete-files).

---

For future precaution you use *Inotify Tools*. then you can use the `inotifywait` command to listen for events happening for the specified directory.

Specifically if you want to watch for deleted files and folder use this

```
inotifywait -m -r -e delete directory_name
```

and log this output in some file.

And I would also recommend you to look for [iwatch](http://iwatch.sourceforge.net/index.html).

Comment: The `debugfs` way works a lot better in theory than it does in practice.  It takes forever and a day to resolve a name from an inode, and chances of still having useful information after ~30 days are rather slim.  It _might_ let you recover an important file that you deleted accidentally, if you switch to single user and run `debugfs` immediately.  For many files deleted a long time ago, even if you only want the filenames, it probably isn't worth the pain.  The `inotify` way works nicely for logging fs operations, but of course you need to have it running before deleting the files.

Comment: @SatoKatsura yes, you are right. but OP has already left with nowhere. I gave possible workaround to get him/her on track. and for `inotify` I have clearly mentioned, *For future precaution*.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't trying to contradict anything in your post, just adding some warning about what it means.

Comment: @SatoKatsura No need to apologize. Glad to know your help.